# override jmeter.proprties file values inside the test plan

Tags: jmeter

It started as some relatively simple thing... formatting the epoch timestamp on listener output file.
on default behavior it gives you 13 digit epoch timestamp. but i want it to be human readable formatted string.

the obvious solution is to uncomment the following line in the jmeter.properties file:

jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

However, this is true to just a single test plan i run, i don't want to change this behavior by editing properties file every time (really inconvenient and requires a restart every time when i want to switch to tests plans in which i do want the epoch time to work with digits)

so i tried to override this property in every single way, and failed.
i tried using beanshell script or javascript (in preprocessors, postprocessors, jsr223 samplers etc...) to change it using vars.setProperty or using __setProperty jmeter function
all failed.

also saw somewhere i can pass it as runtime argument, but i start jmeter using some batch file that fails every time i try to pass the line on cmd.

Is there any way to change this property dynamically from inside the jmx file? or am i doomed to forever edit the properties file and restart jmeter every time i switch my testPlans... (since in some of them i actually do want epoch timestamp)

thanks
tal

Answer (score 0):

In Non-GUI mode, pass the value as `JMeter Property` using `-J` as follows:

```
jmeter.bat -n -t "examples\Debug Sampler.jmx" -l examples\log.jtl -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

and it worked for me.

---

Within the Test Plan using `__setProperty`, I am not aware of any solution/work around. Changing the JMeter property, `timestamp_format`,  does not result in saving the results in the changed format.

Comment: your runTime argument solution from command line worked for me (both in load mode or ui mode). however, when i try to remove the runtime argument and rely only on the beanshell sampler script you used, it doesn't work in either mode (with/without ui). can you share on which version you it worked for you? it miht be some kind of regression (i'm using jmeter 3.1)

Comment: I've also used `3.1` version.

Comment: strange... can you tell me what is your java version? could be related to the JVM version or something... (sorry about annoying you with these questions, i'm asking you because if i can understand where this issue is coming from i want to open a defect to the project, its a bit cumbersome to do it using runtime arguments...)

Comment: `Java 1.8`. I'm sorry for the wrong conclusion. Changing the `timestamp_format` did not work for me. Though the value change is reflected in the `Debug Sampler` name, this did not yield in producing the results in given time format, when results are saved. I don't think so, there could be a way to change this property within the test plan. You must choose `-J` argument from command line instead from the Test Plan.